# Python import csv to lists with multiple rows

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, import

I want to import a database.csv that contains 4 values

```
key,email1,email2,email3
filename,email@example.com,email2@example.com,email3@example.com
filename2,email@yahoo.com,email@google.com,email@outlook.com
etc,etc,etc,etc
```

Next I want to separate the column key to equal a list of filenames, and email1, email2, and email3 to another list

```
key = [filename]
emails = [email@example.com,email2@example.com,email3@example.com]
```

Current code

```
import csv
with open('data.csv') as read_csv:
reader = csv.reader(read_csv)
for row in reader:
    key = row[0]
    emails = row[1::]
return key
return emails
```

Output is

```
key = [filename2]
emails = [filename2,email@yahoo.com,email@google.com,email@outlook.com]
```

What I need is the key to match correspondingly with the emails to pass to another function.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary sounds like the appropriate solution here.

```
import csv
result = {}
with open('data.csv') as read_csv:
    reader = csv.reader(read_csv)
    for row in reader:
        result[row[0]] = row[1:]
```

You can then always access or pass on the values like this:

```
result[filename2]
```

Comment: Aah good point, I just copied the OP code blindly for that part. I'll fix that. Not being in a function, we don't need the return part.

Comment: How am I able to assign the 'key' column to the variable key and email1, email2, email3 to the variable 'emails' ?

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with Python dictionaries, I would strongly encourage you to [read up on them](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) - they are incredibly useful, especially for something you are considering to do, if I understand correctly.

Basically after looping through each 'row', you will have a structure that looks like this:
`result = {'key1': [email1_a, email2_a, email3_a],
   'key2': [email1_b, email2_b, email3_b]}`

You can then call any key-value pair from the key using result['key1'] and it will give you the corresponding list.